# Centering text in HTML

Tags: html

The `<center>Text</center>` tag to have text centered horizontally is depreciated, so I tried `<p align="center">Text</p>` although I read it does not work in all browsers. When I have a header `<h#>` tag within a `<p>` tag there is a validation issue. Although the center tag is tolerable, it is apparently not the best way. Why has it been depreciated? And what is the alternative?

Using accepted answer's `<p style="text-align:center"></p>` I am not able to center `<h>` tags within `<p>` tags. I read `<h# align="center">` does not work in all browsers and tried applying the style to the header tag, to no avail.

Comment: No actually an answer but you should check how to use CSS. It's the new black :)

Comment: I do use CSS but I feel that it is very sloppy unless I make a style just for centering.

Comment: You don't have to create a new style. Just use it "inline".

Comment: The style="text-align:center;" centers inline elements. H# tags are block elements, so you can just set them as inline (or inline-block) (display: inline;).

Comment: To center H# elements without changing the display style, you could use the CSS children selection: p.centered H1, p.centered H2, etc. { text-align: center; }

Comment: Do not put `h` tags in `p` tags.  Just don't it's bad xhtml and will not validate, and so any CSS or anything you do is not guaranteed to work.  Don't get attached to using header tags, just learn some CSS and it will set you free!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The text alignment needs to be declared in CSS.  You can do this in a CSS section at the top of the file, in a separate file, or in the element itself.  The simplest method would be the latter (note that this method is not generally considered a good practice):

```
<p style="text-align: center">Text</p>
```

If you want to put it at the top of the html file, it would look like this:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
p.centered
{
  text-align:center;
}

--> 
</style>
</head>
<body>
...
  <p class="centered">Text</p>
</body>
```

The best method would be to have a separate CSS stylesheet containing the CSS.  Then, add a link to the CSS in the `<head></head>` section of your html:

```
<head>
<link href="path/to/file/name.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: I feel that this is a sloppy way of doing things.

Comment: If you use a CSS Stylesheet, you can clean it up much nicer.  The idea of CSS is so you don't have all these style tags strewn throughout HTML.  Simply tag the <p> with a class and define the style in an external stylesheet.

Comment: On second thought, I can make a class for it. It could be <p class="center"></p>. Thank you.

Comment: this is *absolutely* how you do it.  You can also decide to automatically center elements in a style block & avoid the hard coded styles.  

#header h1 {
   text-align: center;
}

Comment: class="center" is not a good idea...  You need to separate the "what" from the "how it looks"

For example, these are poor choices for class names:
leftDiv
blueBg
borderRed

These would be better:
header
tagline
navigation
external_link

the class should specify the "what" and the style should target those and give appropriate CSS to style it.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason <h> tags that are within the <p> tags will not center, how would I go about centering the <h> tags without changing my current css for them?

Comment: Adding the style="text-align: center" attribute to the h tags will center them as well

Answer (score 2):

```
<p style="text-align:center;">Some Text Here</p>
```

That will do the trick for you

Answer (score 2):

try `<p style="text-align: center;">Text</p>`

or at the top of your html you can declare:

```
<style type="text/css">
.center { text-align: center; }
</style>
```

then later just apply the class:

```
<p class="center">Text</p>
```

just remember the text-align css property will work for block elements.

Answer (score 2):

To address the implied second question, the reason you have validation issues when you have a <h#> inside a <p> is because nesting headers inside of paragraphs is not allowed in HTML 4.0 and XHTML.

To expound, headings and paragraphs are semantic concepts, meant to inform the structure of your document and not imply anything about the appearance of their content (granted, they do appear different by default but that's not the point of their usage). It follows that a heading shouldn't be contained within a paragraph.

If your implementation calls for nesting headers inside of paragraphs you might want to rethink your approach to what you're trying to accomplish. If the intent is to indicate structurally "this is a heading", consider why a heading would be inside a paragraph. If the intent is to make certain text within a paragraph look different, then you would want to use one of the [inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) elements such as a span or em, with associated CSS styling.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding a `<h#>` tag within a `<p>` tag, that is indeed a validation issue.

`<h#>` tags are meant to mark up headings. `<p>` tags are meant to mark up paragraphs.

So, if I was marking up your question, I might start like this:

```
<h2>Centering Text in HTML</h2>

<p>I know at first this seems like a very stupid question, but I have a good reason for asking it. Even though I might just be misled.</p>
```

If I wanted the heading to be center aligned, I’d again use CSS:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Centering Text in HTML</h2>

<p>I know at first this seems like a very stupid question, but I have a good reason for asking it. Even though I might just be misled.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The politically correct way to do it is CSS.

Try to do something like:

```
<p style="text-align:center">Text</p>
```

Or even better, use a CSS stylesheet.

Really, you should not be using in-line CSS either, it is just as sloppy.  You can define a style for all `<p>` tags, or attach a class like `<p class="header"` and define the `header` class in CSS like:

`p.header { text-align: center }`

This way your style is separated from your HTML, producing a much cleaner HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want center text you can do it by using the "text-align: center" css declaration:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">Centered Text</div>
```

If you want to center an element you would give it a width and set the "margin: 0 auto" like this:

```
<div style="width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;>whole div will be centered</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the question of separating (... or not) styling from content, it's worth mentioning that "official" deprecation from HTML does not mean that it does not work as well as it has.
Given the way browsers work and get developed, your center tag will keep on working for a while, possibly until end of time HTML itself is used. :-)

That is, change it if you feel it's the right thing to do, but not if you think it doesn't work any more. Plus: removing it if it works and alternatives don't... well, I wouldn't change it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I know you specified "HTML" in your question, so this may not be what you are asking... but have you considered the CSS styles:

```
style="text-align:center;"
```

or

```
style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I **highly** recommend you read [CSS Mastery](http://cssmastery.com) by Andy Budd.  It's a great book, a quick read, and it will definitely change your mind about how you view CSS.

Given your comments about CSS I think you'd get a lot out of this book.

Answer (score 0):

It was deprecated because it's a style that can't be controlled dynamically. It also doesn't let you separate your markup from your style.

Text can only be centered in the box element it resides in so text that you want centered has to be in a <p> or <div> or <td>, etc. You can't center text in a  for instance.

text-align is the css attribute that replaced

Your other questions seem to have been adequately answered.

Answer (score 0):

The best and most versatile way to handle this is for your < p> tags to inherit from their parent class, like so:

```
<style>
.paragraph p{
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div class="paragraph">
   <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

That way, when you want to style your website differently later on, you have a centralized location to change all < p> tags within the "paragraph" class and don't have to change them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You should be transitioning to CSS for style. HTML / XHTML are intended to be purely for content.

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Paragraph Text</p>
```

Also, I don't believe that `<h#>` tags should be nested within `<p>` tags.

For more info, see [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Hehe, well it's not as easy as it may seem. What I usually do is have all text inside divs, and then use the "text-align" css tag. As for the center tag, no idea.

Good luck :-)